# Android Send Data via Blue Tooth Low Energy adapter

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to **send "text" from android device to a LED panel via a "BLE" adapter.**

I am able to connect the android device with the "BLE adapter" through the following sample project. As this is an open-source project, i have no problems in the connection part.
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothLeGatt

Now, i want to send data (say "Hello World") from the device to the ble adapter. I find a project on Google Play and it would send data successfully to the "BLE Adapter" as shown below
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ingics.uc.serialble.v2

However, **this is not an open-source project and there are no ways for me to work it out programmatically.**

I have searched github and found some projects claming they would send data to bluetooth devices but i still would not work it out.
https://github.com/suzp1984/Light_BLE
https://github.com/Lembed/Android-BLE-Terminal

I know "BLE" is a big topic here but the objective i want to achieve is very simple. Great if anyone would share with me some "**simple sample projects**" for me to achieve my goal.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I made this project to make a connection between my Android device and a bluetooth module (HC-06) (and it worked perfectly). You may want to give it a shot for your project!

**https://github.com/omaflak/Bluetooth-Library**

Everything is on the README.md! Good luck